# remove underline in listview android

Tags: android, android-listview

i want to know how to remove underline in display listview in android, can anybody help me?

this is my listview xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_mini"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:paddingRight="6dip"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="9px"
android:background="#fff"
/>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try adding this divider tag:

```
<ListView
android:everythingelse = "yourStuff"
android:divider="#00000000" <--- this guy
/>
```

to your XML file that contains the ListView element

Comment: wow it works!, but i have one more question, what properties to change hint colour?

Comment: @Alex Lockwood It's only in the new Jell-O Bean distro ;)

Comment: @sephtian android:textColorHint="#FFFFFFFF" , perhaps, from a quick google search.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: @jack57, hmm not working.. i want to change the "yellow" when i click one of listview item

Comment: Well, this is almost worth another question that I could answer for you haha ;), but you're going to need to do this programmatically.  Create an OnItemClickListener for your ListView, and from there set a selected listView item and update the adapter for the list.  You're probably going to need a custom ListViewAdapter for all this as well if you want to continue to make specific changes with the ListView

Answer (score 1):

Simple and the soluton

```
 android:divider="@null"
 android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```